# Azure Repo Git Integration With Atlassian Jira

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jira, jira-plugin, azure-repos

At work we are using Azure repositories as version control and Jira for our project management needs and issue management. We wanted to integrate both of these platform, so I sucsseffully installed `Azure Pipeline For Jira` and tested it out with a demo repo on Github with `Github for Jira` and it worked, it integrated my git actions on issue pannels. But somehow it does not support the Azure repos (at least there is no free version).

Let me know if any one has a work around for this. (Obviously not paid)

My main Question is, now I am trying to use Azure webhooks to receive information regarding my git activity on Jira issue pannel. In order to receive this information I am trying to create a web trigger URL in Jira's Forge App but couldn't really make it work. Maybe the URL generated by Jira is too big or something it gives 424 error when GET request is sent to the URL. Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: It seems that only third-party paid plugins support azure repos.  Please refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira/issues/10).